# boxplots using matplotlib of a dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a dataset in a spreadsheet in two columns something similar to below:

type [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

value [230, 300, 342, 218, 393, 273, 333, 317, 287, 291]

I want to group the values of 0 types and 1 types and boxplot the three data sets (original set, 0s and 1s) in a single frame.

[image]

I have tried a few different things but none has worked:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import pandas a pd

inData = pd.read_csv(sheet)

x = inData['value']
grouped = inData.groupby(["type"])
out0, out1 = [grouped.get_group(value) for value in grouped.groups]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Box Plot')
data = [out0, value, out1[::2]]
ax1.boxplot(data)

plt.show()
```

Boxplot has to be constructed using python/matplotlibs.

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample dataframe?

Comment: This is pretty much it in the dataframe. I just have two columns in a spreadsheet which I read in using pandas.read_csv. updated the code to indicate the imports and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat` the dataset with itself while assigning a combined label, then use [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'type': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'value': [230, 300, 342, 218, 393, 273, 333, 317, 287, 291]
                  })

sns.boxplot(data=pd.concat([df, df.assign(type='both')]),
            x='type', y='value', order=['both', 0, 1]
           )
```

output:

[image: seaborn boxplot]

#### pure matplotlib solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'value': [230, 300, 342, 218, 393, 273, 333, 317, 287, 291]
                  })
df2 = pd.concat([df, df.assign(type='both')]).groupby('type')['value'].apply(list)

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.boxplot(df2, labels=df2.index)
```

output:

[image: matplotlib boxplot per group]

Comment: I am only allowed to use Matplotlib.

Comment: @droidian you did not mention this was homework, please check the update

Comment: Thank you, I am pretty close. I say that because I cannot get both boxplot to print. I just copy pasted your solution but I only get 0 and 1 boxplots.